# Firebase Realtime Database onValue does not rebuild the UI

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, stream, real-time

I have the code for get Children and thier locations from realtime database

But the UI did not update when the listen function call [due to update in realtime database]

The print function in listen function is call when data is changed in realtime

```
_childrenList = [];
    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc in data.docs) {
      _childrenList.add(childrenList.fromSnapshot(doc));
      http.Response response =
          await http.get(Uri.parse(_childrenList.last.childImagePath!));
      dbReferences[doc.id] = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("devices/${doc.id}");
      DataSnapshot temp = await dbReferences[doc.id]!.get();
      Map deviceData = temp.value as Map;
      childrenLatLong[doc.id] = {
        "lat": deviceData["lat"],
        "long": deviceData["long"]
      };
      markers[doc.id] = Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(doc.id),
        position: LatLng(
            childrenLatLong[doc.id]!["lat"], childrenLatLong[doc.id]!["long"]),
        // icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(response.bodyBytes),
      );
        dbReferences[doc.id]!.onValue.listen((event) {
          print(event.snapshot.value);
          Map newData = event.snapshot.value as Map;
          setState(() {
            
          markers[doc.id] = Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId(doc.id),
            position: LatLng(childrenLatLong[doc.id]!["lat"],
                childrenLatLong[doc.id]!["long"]),
            // icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(response.bodyBytes),
          );
          });
        });
    }
    setState(() {});
```